# Socket blocking client when sending image

Tags: java, sockets

So I'm making a simple chat where I'm sending content in the form of objects, in this case my problem is that when I'm sending and Image it just blocking my Client!, here's my shortened code.
   I've isolated it mostly to the code below, as I've tested the rest and worked fine, I've also tried debugging this but I just can't seem to find the problem

Image

```
package com.example.mtc.Packets;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Image extends Message implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3188407715959746920L;

    private byte[] content;
    private String type;

    public Image(byte[] content,String type, int sourceID,int destinationID,String sourceUsername) {
        super(destinationID,sourceID,sourceUsername);
        this.content = content;
        this.type = "." + type;
    }

    public byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

ClientReaderThread:

```
        while (true) {
            try {
                inputData = in.readObject();
                if (inputData.getClass().getName().equals("com.example.mtc.Packets.Image")) {
                    Image imagePacket = (Image) inputData;
                    byte[] imageContent = imagePacket.getContent();
                    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageContent);
                    imageIcon.setImage(imageIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(300, 300, java.awt.Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                    if (imagePacket.getDestinationID() == 0) {
                        if (Cliente.selectedChat == 0) {
                            Style style = chatCard.doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);
                            StyleConstants.setIcon(style, imageIcon);
                            chatCard.doc.insertString(chatCard.doc.getLength(), "ignored text\n", style);
                            chatCard.textPane.setCaretPosition(chatCard.textPane.getDocument().getLength());
                            Cliente.gui.revalidate();
                        }
                    } else if (imagePacket.getSourceID() == Cliente.selectedChat
                            || imagePacket.getSourceID() == Cliente.getUserID()) {
                        Style style = chatCard.doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);
                        StyleConstants.setIcon(style, imageIcon);
                        chatCard.doc.insertString(chatCard.doc.getLength(), "ignored text\n", style);
                        chatCard.textPane.setCaretPosition(chatCard.textPane.getDocument().getLength());
                        Cliente.gui.revalidate();
                    }

                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Cliente.gui, "Couldn't connect to Server!", "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Server Listener

```
private void Listener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (connected) {
            inputData = readObject();
            if (inputData != null) {
                if (inputData.getClass().getName().equals("com.example.mtc.Packets.Image")) {

                    Image imagePacket = (Image) inputData;
                    byte[] imageContent = imagePacket.getContent();
                    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageContent);
                    imageIcon.setImage(imageIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(300, 300,
                            java.awt.Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

                    imageIcon.getImage().flush();
                    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                            imageIcon.getIconWidth(),
                            imageIcon.getIconHeight(),
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                        Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
                        // paint the Icon to the BufferedImage.
                        imageIcon.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
                        g.dispose();

                    try {
                        File imageFile = File.createTempFile("image", imagePacket.getType(),
                                new File("./serverImages/"));
                        insertLog(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), imagePacket.getDestinationID(), true);
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try {
                                    Files.write(imageFile.toPath(), imageContent);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }).start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (imagePacket.getDestinationID() == 0) {

                        synchronized (Server.Threads) {
                            for (ClientHandler t : Server.Threads) {
                                if (!idExistsInBlockedList(t.getUserID(), userID)) {
                                    t.sendObject(imagePacket);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        synchronized (Server.Threads) {
                            for (ClientHandler t : Server.Threads) {
                                if (!idExistsInBlockedList(t.getUserID(), userID)) {
                                    if (t.getUserID() == imagePacket.getDestinationID()) {
                                        t.sendObject(imagePacket);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            sendObject(imagePacket);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, as you called it, this option should be treated as multi threaded. This seem well done but is there any stack trace to help us out ?

Comment: That's the problem! no stack trace what so ever just plain out freezes the swing GUI, It also doesn't crash immediatly, so it most likely only crashes when trying to display the content received in the GUI

Comment: I have bit of an idea but i´m not sure at all. The fact is that swing components should be used in swing threads. Use Platform.runLater(Runnable) to do this. Try this trick but i can not guarantee you that it will work

Comment: THANK YOUUUU, managed to make it work with the SwingUtilities.invokeLater!

Comment: No problem, i’ll post it as an answer later on in the day

Comment: Freezes? Crashes? You're engaging in blocking I/O. It *blocks.*

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(), as advised by [R.L.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10707187/r-lm)